# Stuck on deploy express / next app to netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, netlify

I'm stuck to deploy my Next/Express app on Netlify.

The app works fine locally but when I want to build on using Netlify lambda function it doesn't work.

Here my git repos for some test : https://github.com/Lazy974/NextExpress

If I only use `next build` script, the app can be deployed but I can't use express but if I use the Netlify script `netlify-lambda build (src/directory)` I get this error:

> Can't resolve 'pnpapi' in '.../Express_Next/node_modules/pnp-webpack-plugin'

If I use the basically script server.js (without next configuration) it works but not locally.

Comment: Have you tried using [`next-on-netlify`](https://github.com/netlify/next-on-netlify)?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem. Here's my work-around:

1. Use Nextjs's default "custom server configuration" to run express on your app.
2. If your app runs as expected locally, go to package.json and do the following changes:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node directory/server.js",
  "build:server": "tsc --project jsconfig.server.json",
  "build:next": "next build",
  "build": "npm run build:next && npm run build:server",
  "export": "next build && next export",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node directory/server.js"
}
```

3. Create `jsconfig.server.json` in root directory (same level as package.json), and enter the following:

```json
{
  "extends": "./jsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": ["server"]
}
```

This should enable your nextjs+expressjs to deploy on netlify.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Instead of express you can use the [NextJS API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes)

Netlify doesn't support a server. So if you want to run Next.JS with a custom express server I would recommend using something like Heroku.